# Center <p> in <div> with left alignment?

Tags: html, css

```
<body>    
    <div class="about">
        <p>Love<br>
        Robots
        </p>
    </div>
</body>
```

I want to make `Love Robots`
with left alignment, but in the center of whole page

Like text and headers in this site: https://deadblog.ru/webdev/vyravnivanie-div-blokov-po-centru-css/

Result will be:

```
begin|    cen|ter    |end

          Love
          Robots
          Another Text
```

Not like:

```
begin|    cen|ter    |end

            Love
           Robots
        Another Text
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `flex` with `justify-content: center` like below (for single child)

```
.about {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```css
.about {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="about">
  <p>Love<br> Robots
  </p>
</div>
```

**For multiple child elements**

```css
.about {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}


/* incase if you need to remove default spacing */

.about p {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="about">
    <p>Love<br> Robots
    </p>
    <p>Love<br> Robots again
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It works, but it doesn't if i add second <p>

Comment: @gelerum `flex-direction:column` for multiple child elements in that case

Comment: @gelerum Updated for multiple `p` elements

Answer (score 2):

Surround your original `div` with another one, and adjust the css for `.about` to match this:

```css
.center {
  text-align: center;
}

.about {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="center">
    <div class="about">
      <p>Love<br> Robots
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: +1 , I used to do like this, later moved to `flex` but for any reason if flex don't work, I still use this method.